# How to make a second signer dependant on the first one's choice? Conditional tabs and signers

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to create a specific workflow using the C# SDK of DocuSing.

The idea is, the first signer will have a choice in the signature process, this choice will determine the place of signature of next signers. This choices are 2 checkboxes.

This is the scenario: in a clause within the document, the first signer have 2 choices (checkboxes), when the first signer check one, a initial tab will be showed (the place depend on which checkbox has been checked). The next signers will not be able to modify the checkbox checked, but their inital tab place must be dependant on the choice of the first signer.

For now, I wasn't able to achieve this scenario. The initial tabs are always visibles in signature process (the idea is have these inital tabs hidden until first signer checks one of the checkboxes) and they are mandatory to be signed, but once the document is signed, the signed version only shows the proper initial tab (only whose that the checkbox has been selected).
Is it possible to hidden the initial tabs until a checkbox is selected? Can these initial tabs be make not "required"?

But my main concern is the dependat of the next signers. Until now I tried to bind next signer's initial tabs to first signer's checkboxes, but without success.

Here is the code:

```
var signer1 = new Signer()
{
    Email = recipient1Email,
    Name = recipient1Name,
    RecipientId = "1",
    RoutingOrder = "1",
    Tabs = new Tabs()
    {
        CheckboxTabs = new List<Checkbox>()
        {
            new Checkbox()
            {
                TabLabel = "Choice1",
                Selected = "false",
                DocumentId = "1",
                AnchorString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Signer1_Choice1"]
            },
            new Checkbox()
            {
                TabLabel = "Choice2",
                Selected = "false",
                DocumentId = "1",
                AnchorString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Signer1_Choice2"]
            }
        },
        InitialHereTabs = new List<InitialHere>()
        {
            new InitialHere()
            {
                ConditionalParentLabel = "Choice1",
                ConditionalParentValue = "On",
                Name = "signer1initials1",
                DocumentId = "1",
                RecipientId = "1",
                TabLabel = "Signer1Initials1",
                AnchorString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Signer1_Choice1_Initials"]
            },
            new InitialHere()
            {
                ConditionalParentLabel = "Choice2",
                ConditionalParentValue = "On",
                Name = "signer1initials2",
                DocumentId = "1",
                RecipientId = "1",
                TabLabel = "Signer1Initials2",
                AnchorString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Signer1_Choice2_Initials"]
            }
        }
    }
};

var signer2 = new Signer()
{
    Email = recipient2Email,
    Name = recipient2Name,
    RecipientId = "2",
    RoutingOrder = "2",
    Tabs = new Tabs()
    {
        InitialHereTabs = new List<InitialHere>()
        {
            new InitialHere()
            {
                Name = "signer2initials1",
                DocumentId = "1",
                RecipientId = "2",
                TabLabel = "Signer2Initials1",
                AnchorString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Signer2_Choice1_Initials"],
                ConditionalParentLabel = "Choice1",
                ConditionalParentValue = "On"
            },
            new InitialHere()
            {
                Name = "signer2initials2",
                DocumentId = "1",
                RecipientId = "2",
                TabLabel = "Signer2Initials2",
                AnchorString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Signer2_Choice2_Initials"],
                ConditionalParentLabel = "Choice2",
                ConditionalParentValue = "On"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I'm most concern on the choice of the first signer will be reflected in the next signers, the required tabs or show/not show tabs issues are not very important.

Can someone help me? Maybe I'm wrong in this approach? DOn't know, this is my first time with DocuSign SDK and signature process.

Also, I'm not using templates or any other thing than C# SDK. The document is generated by another app and the tabs are anchored to specific words.

Regards,
Alvaro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario is complicated and will require extra API calls but is doable.

1. Create and send envelope with 2 Signers with notifications Recipient events **Recipient Signed/Completed**, [guide here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/connect-webhooks-json-notifications)
2. Once the Signer1 signs the envelope, you will be notified
3. Get envelope signer tags info using this [endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/list/)
4. Your logic for the next steps based on Signer choice
5. Update your envelope based on step 5

Comment: There's a caveat to the suggested approach - you don't want a "quick" second signer to get into the envelope before you are able to make changes.  You can either use a bogus captive recipient to block envelope progress or you can lock the envelope until done.
Captive recipient technique:  signers in routing order sequence:
1, signer1
2, "Blocker", "blocker@example.com", clientUserId: "blocker@example.com"
3, signer2

After you finish making updates for signer2, do a PUT to remove Blocker in routing order 2.  The Blocker prevents signer2 from receiving a notice until you're done.

Comment: @WTP, Thank you for your suggestion. I think that actually locking the envelope is a safer strategy.

Comment: IvanD Thanks for your idea. @WTP thanks as well for your suggestion. This looks more complicated than I expected, I though this can be achieve using the SDK, but if I have to build an endpoint and more (far more) logic, maybe doesn't make sense to try it. I'm developing a proof of concept, so for now I think I leave as currently is. I will try this workaround as soon as I have couple of hours free and let you know. Many thanks to both!